# Angular 5 dynamically add & delete a component instance

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

I'm trying to create a table that looks like a spreadsheet with editable inputs inside each `td`. I'm using Angular's `ComponentFactoryResolver` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47535780/angular-5-adding-a-new-instance-of-a-component), to add a row to the table when user clicks the add button.

Once the row is added, I use `EventEmitter` to emit all the data of that row as the last column value is changed.

I've tried to re implement the same functionality on [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ees3kn).

I'm having the following issues:

1. I'm unable to emit data from the newly added components. (Check Console)
2. Once I add a new row, the first row (not dynamic) also stops giving me the emitted data.
3. I'm not sure how to delete a row if user don't needs it as I don't have the reference to it.

Comment: How about coming up with another solution than ComponentFactoryResolver?

Comment: Can you suggest any? I spent a lot of time to find this solution. If you could suggest a better solution I'd try to implement that.

Comment: let me create a stackblitz.

Comment: How about something like this? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vdyhib

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I am suggesting. You can create a list of row objects in the parent (table) component and use *ngFor to loop it over.

```
<app-row 
   *ngFor="let row of rowList" 
   [row]="row" 
   (entryUpdate)="onEntryUpdated($event)">
</app-row>
```

Please have a look at [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vdyhib)

Comment: Many Thanks, Can you also recommend something regarding deleting a specific row?

Comment: Stackblitz updated. Please have look and sir if this is the answer you were looking, please mark it as accepted. May be you can come-up with a better solution for removing elements from array.

Comment: Thank you, I've got a right path to work on. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Happy that I could help. :)

Comment: I agree this is the better way to go

Comment: @RukshanDangalla https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2xtrfj I'm trying to add headers on top. The styling gets messed up. May be you could have a look please. Look at the template of table.component. Thanks

Comment: Here is fixed stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rb3im2 What I did was, add attribute selector instead of normal selector. You can read more about this on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34588933/how-to-remove-replace-the-angular2-components-selector-tag-from-html

Comment: I understand what you did there. It fixed the issues however, I had to write some CSS to fix the resulting style issues. Thanks Mate.